# Using a Variable in WHERE clause does not work

Tags: php

I'm running a simple query that is working, that is, without a PHP variable in the WHERE clause.

However, when I insert the variable, it does nothing.

```
<?php 
   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT `rem1` FROM `exam_group_exam_results` WHERE `exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id`= $student_value->id and `exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id`=1");
         $getrem = $query->row();
     echo $getrem->rem1;?>
```

But when I insert just a value, everything works

```
<?php 
   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT `rem1` FROM `exam_group_exam_results` WHERE `exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id`= 11 and `exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id`=1");
         $getrem = $query->row();
     var_dump($getrem);?>
```

I var_dump this variable `student_value['id']` and it printed out the correct value which is 11.

I've been at this for hours. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to assign the value of your object to another variable.
Example

```
$id_value = student_value['id'];
```

Then use the variable in your SQL code

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT `rem1` FROM `exam_group_exam_results` WHERE `exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id`= $id_value and `exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id`=1");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a syntax problem

```
   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT `rem1` FROM `exam_group_exam_results` WHERE `exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id`= ".$student_value->id." and `exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id`=1");
```

Otherwise, check whether your variable is an object or an array

Comment: that didn't work either. I printed ```$student_value``` and this is what I got ```array(48) { ["id"]=> string(2) "11"
["exam_group_class_batch_exam_id"]=> string(1) "1"
["student_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["student_session_id"]=>
string(1) "1" ["roll_no"]=> string(1) "0" ["no_atten"]=>
string(1) "0" ["no_abs"]=> string(1) "0"```

Comment: `student_value['id']` and `student_value->id` are not the same thing. The former works when you print it out, because `student_value` is an array, as you've just confirmed. So use that in your SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

I think the query syntax is not read the Student ID, so the result will show as is WHERE CLAUSE.

```
// Try this
$studentId = $student_value->id;

$sql = "SELECT `rem1` FROM `exam_group_exam_results` WHERE `exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id`=`$studentId` and `exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id`=1"
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. From your suggestion, I did this...                
                                                                                                              
  ```$studentId = $student_value['id'];

$sql = "SELECT `rem1` FROM `exam_group_exam_results` WHERE `exam_group_class_batch_exam_student_id`=`$studentId` and `exam_group_class_batch_exam_subject_id`=1"
$query = $this->db->query($sql);```